# how to print lines in a txt which fulfills certain condition with python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def palindrome_filter(file_name):
    file=open('text_1.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        line=line.rstrip()
        if (is_palindrome(line)):
            print(line)
    file.close()
palindrome_filter('text_1.txt')
```

Above are the codes that I wrote. I actually want python to print the certain line which is a palindrome, but it keeps printing true or false instead. I wonder what's wrong with my code. (function to determine whether a line is palindrome is texted, it is correct.)

Comment: I have given done some changes to your code below.

Comment: Strange. I tried it and it prints out the line and not true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution might be:

```
def palindrome_filter(file_name):
    file=open('text_1.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line == line[::-1]:
            print(line)
    file.close()
```

Comment: I don't really want to judge if the line is a palindrome. Instead, I want to print the lines which are palindrome.

Comment: yeah that what it does

Comment: It works this time. Thank you so much. I still want to know why I couldn't get the palindromes but only true or false using my own code. Thanks if you could help with it.

Comment: Because your script **is_palindrome(line)** returns Boolean not the line